# OpenGL large data 3d plot

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, opengl, vbo

I'm trying to make a 3d plot of large data sets (for example 1000 x 500 points) in which x,y is uniformly spread (for example 0, 8, 16, 24 so on), and z describes a value. I were trying to do this with Qt and OpenGL as in [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Scientific_OpenGL_Tutorial_04). The problem is that i don't know how many points i will need (it varies), but their amount will be large, and on initialization of VBO i need to specify the amount:

```
#define N 256
GLbyte graph[N][N];

... /* fill graph here */

/* Upload the texture with our datapoints */
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glGenTextures(1, &texture_id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, N, N, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, graph);
```

So as in this example, in my case N value would be much higher to hold all the points, but i get stack overflow error. 
What is the best way to cope with this problem? How can i specify not known amount, other than specifying max amount available? Is there another way to optimize generation of 3dplots of large datasets?

Comment: Stack overflow seems to have nothing to do with OpenGL and optimization. It happens because you allocated `graph` on stack. Use heap instead: `GLbyte *graph = new GLbyte[N*N];`

Comment: @Sergey: In C++, especially modern C++, why do you think this is sound advice? Use a `std::vector` of `N*N` elements of type `GLbyte`. Please don't advise people to do manual memory allocation/deallocation - if they **need** to, go ahead, if they don't, they shouldn't.

Comment: @thokra so basicly it does not matter what type of object i put into glTexImage2D? Or how it is specified there?

Comment: @Dario3d: The *type* of the pointer you pass is theoretically irrelevant, since it's type is erased anyway by being implicitly cast to `void*`. However, since the implementation accesses memory starting at the address you provide and by the additional information like `width`, `height` and `type`. So if you don't provide a pointer to memory your process actually owns in it's entirety, your program might crash due to an access violation.

Comment: @Dario3d What type of object is put in glTexImage2D does matter. Casting it as an argument of glTexImage2D has to result in meaningful description of the raw buffer data. It is OK to input std::vector since all implementations of the c++ standard library guarantee continuous storage of data in a vector.